# What is the difference between _.initial and _.dropRight?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

In the Lodash library, what is the difference between `_.initial` and `_.dropRight`? As far as I can see, both lead to the same result:

```
_.initial([1,2,3])    ->  [1,2]
_.dropRight([1,2,3])  ->  [1,2]
```

The only formal difference is that `_.dropRight` takes an optional second argument, but adding that to `_.initial` wouldn't hurt. So why isn't `_.initial` just an alias to `_.dropRight`?

Is there any subtle difference I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

From the [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.0.0-npm/array/initial.js#L16) for v3:

```
var dropRight = require('./dropRight');

function initial(array) {
  return dropRight(array, 1);
}

module.exports = initial;
```

`_.initial` makes a direct call to `dropRight`.

The reason [`_.initial`](https://lodash.com/docs#initial) isn't an alias though is notice the argument difference.  With [`_.dropRight`](https://lodash.com/docs#dropRight), you are able to specify the number of items to drop, whereas initial will always drop the last item.

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I still don't understand *why* _.initial cannot be made an alias. What's wrong  with _.initial accepting a second argument?

Comment: although this is an old thread, I just stumbled upon it after I created this issue: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2457
Lets see if we get an answer or if they even make it an alias.